# Running tensorflow stuck after "Creating Tensor devices"

Tags: tensorflow

I ran [some tensorflow code](https://github.com/andabi/deep-voice-conversion) on 
a server like this:

- 8 Nvidia GTX1080
- about 40G graphics of memory
- 200GB of memory

but the progress will always stop on " Creating TensorFlow device" and don't show any more infomation, and the terminial was dead.
Other tf project works well but this would always fail.

```
2017-11-20 23:32:51.701175: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-20 23:32:51.701252: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-20 23:32:51.701280: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-20 23:32:51.701293: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-20 23:32:51.701320: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-20 23:32:52.552691: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:940] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7335
pciBusID 0000:04:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 1.32GiB
2017-11-20 23:32:53.059142: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:523] A non-primary context 0x842f610 exists before initializing the StreamExecutor. We haven't verified StreamExecutor works with that.
2017-11-20 23:32:53.060813: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:940] Found device 1 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7335
pciBusID 0000:05:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 7.70GiB
2017-11-20 23:32:53.582481: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:523] A non-primary context 0x8433370 exists before initializing the StreamExecutor. We haven't verified StreamExecutor works with that.
2017-11-20 23:32:53.584843: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:940] Found device 2 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7335
pciBusID 0000:08:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 1.16GiB
2017-11-20 23:32:54.094126: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:523] A non-primary context 0x84370d0 exists before initializing the StreamExecutor. We haven't verified StreamExecutor works with that.
2017-11-20 23:32:54.095696: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:940] Found device 3 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7335
pciBusID 0000:09:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 1.82GiB
2017-11-20 23:32:54.633158: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:523] A non-primary context 0x843ae30 exists before initializing the StreamExecutor. We haven't verified StreamExecutor works with that.
2017-11-20 23:32:54.634412: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:940] Found device 4 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7335
pciBusID 0000:84:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 1.80GiB
2017-11-20 23:32:55.226210: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:523] A non-primary context 0x843eb90 exists before initializing the StreamExecutor. We haven't verified StreamExecutor works with that.
2017-11-20 23:32:55.227841: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:940] Found device 5 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7335
pciBusID 0000:85:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 4.79GiB
2017-11-20 23:32:55.789872: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:523] A non-primary context 0x84428f0 exists before initializing the StreamExecutor. We haven't verified StreamExecutor works with that.
2017-11-20 23:32:55.790904: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:940] Found device 6 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7335
pciBusID 0000:88:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 773.00MiB
2017-11-20 23:32:56.371886: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:523] A non-primary context 0x8446650 exists before initializing the StreamExecutor. We haven't verified StreamExecutor works with that.
2017-11-20 23:32:56.373006: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:940] Found device 7 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7335
pciBusID 0000:89:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 1001.00MiB
2017-11-20 23:32:56.374795: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 0 and 4
2017-11-20 23:32:56.374826: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 0 and 5
2017-11-20 23:32:56.374838: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 0 and 6
2017-11-20 23:32:56.374850: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 0 and 7
2017-11-20 23:32:56.375122: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 1 and 4
2017-11-20 23:32:56.375151: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 1 and 5
2017-11-20 23:32:56.375178: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 1 and 6
2017-11-20 23:32:56.375189: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 1 and 7
2017-11-20 23:32:56.375359: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 2 and 4
2017-11-20 23:32:56.375374: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 2 and 5
2017-11-20 23:32:56.375385: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 2 and 6
2017-11-20 23:32:56.375397: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 2 and 7
2017-11-20 23:32:56.375465: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 3 and 4
2017-11-20 23:32:56.375477: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 3 and 5
2017-11-20 23:32:56.375490: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 3 and 6
2017-11-20 23:32:56.375501: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 3 and 7
2017-11-20 23:32:56.375513: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 4 and 0
2017-11-20 23:32:56.375524: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 4 and 1
2017-11-20 23:32:56.375536: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 4 and 2
2017-11-20 23:32:56.375548: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 4 and 3
2017-11-20 23:32:56.377945: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 5 and 0
2017-11-20 23:32:56.378028: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 5 and 1
2017-11-20 23:32:56.378052: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 5 and 2
2017-11-20 23:32:56.378074: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 5 and 3
2017-11-20 23:32:56.378504: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 6 and 0
2017-11-20 23:32:56.378528: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 6 and 1
2017-11-20 23:32:56.378556: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 6 and 2
2017-11-20 23:32:56.378591: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 6 and 3
2017-11-20 23:32:56.378883: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 7 and 0
2017-11-20 23:32:56.378912: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 7 and 1
2017-11-20 23:32:56.378936: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 7 and 2
2017-11-20 23:32:56.378959: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 7 and 3
2017-11-20 23:32:56.379568: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:961] DMA: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2017-11-20 23:32:56.379591: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 0:   Y Y Y Y N N N N
2017-11-20 23:32:56.379607: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 1:   Y Y Y Y N N N N
2017-11-20 23:32:56.379621: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 2:   Y Y Y Y N N N N
2017-11-20 23:32:56.379635: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 3:   Y Y Y Y N N N N
2017-11-20 23:32:56.379651: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 4:   N N N N Y Y Y Y
2017-11-20 23:32:56.379664: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 5:   N N N N Y Y Y Y
2017-11-20 23:32:56.379680: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 6:   N N N N Y Y Y Y
2017-11-20 23:32:56.379694: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 7:   N N N N Y Y Y Y
2017-11-20 23:32:56.379724: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:04:00.0)
2017-11-20 23:32:56.379742: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:1) -> (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0)
2017-11-20 23:32:56.379757: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:2) -> (device: 2, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:08:00.0)
2017-11-20 23:32:56.379772: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:3) -> (device: 3, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:09:00.0)
2017-11-20 23:32:56.379786: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:4) -> (device: 4, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:84:00.0)
2017-11-20 23:32:56.379800: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:5) -> (device: 5, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:85:00.0)
2017-11-20 23:32:56.379816: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:6) -> (device: 6, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:88:00.0)
2017-11-20 23:32:56.379829: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:7) -> (device: 7, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:89:00.0)
```

while the `nvidia-smi`shows:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.66                 Driver Version: 375.66                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 0000:04:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 56%   76C    P2   161W / 180W |   6652MiB /  8114MiB |     98%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 0000:05:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 24%   38C    P8    11W / 180W |    115MiB /  8114MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 0000:08:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 24%   42C    P8    12W / 180W |   6820MiB /  8114MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 0000:09:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 24%   44C    P8    12W / 180W |   6142MiB /  8114MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   4  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 0000:84:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 67%   82C    P2   179W / 180W |   6160MiB /  8114MiB |    100%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   5  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 0000:85:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 48%   71C    P2    81W / 180W |   3094MiB /  8114MiB |     76%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   6  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 0000:88:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 25%   58C    P2    51W / 180W |   7230MiB /  8114MiB |     66%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   7  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 0000:89:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 26%   59C    P2    52W / 180W |   7002MiB /  8114MiB |     90%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     17811    C   python                                         327MiB |
|    0     21873    C   python                                         254MiB |
|    0     25407    C   ../../caffe/build/tools/caffe                 6065MiB |
|    1     17811    C   python                                         113MiB |
|    2     17811    C   python                                         113MiB |
|    2     22605    C   python                                        6705MiB |
|    3     17811    C   python                                         113MiB |
|    3     22605    C   python                                        6027MiB |
|    4      8984    C   ./build/tools/caffe                           6045MiB |
|    4     17811    C   python                                         113MiB |
|    5     17811    C   python                                         113MiB |
|    5     21873    C   python                                        2977MiB |
|    6     13442    C   python                                        7115MiB |
|    6     17811    C   python                                         113MiB |
|    7     13442    C   python                                        6887MiB |
|    7     17811    C   python                                         113MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As it did't raise any CUDA memory error, and the memory is enough and was using (I saw CPU was using a little), I don't think it's an resource question....But, I stuck for over 20hrs...Could anyone help me with it?
Thanks alot.

Comment: Looks that at least some of the devices are being used. Are you sure it's not just your script running? Do you have some logging message just after creating the session? With no code at all is hard to tell what might be the problem. On the other hand, it seems that you are also running caffe, have you made sure not to use the same GPU with both frameworks at the same time?

Comment: Thank you, I think I got the reason. It was extremely lacking of GPU memory, even when I turn batch_size from 16 to 4，the GPU memory was immediately all used.

Comment: @jdehesa yes, I am using this server with other of my group members, they are using CAFFE too.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue when I was using Tensorflow dataset API with tfrecords 2.x, I had around 24k tfrecords, My Previous data pipeline was

```
def load_training_tfrecords(record_mask_file,SHUFFLE):
dataset=tf.data.Dataset.list_files(record_mask_file).interleave(lambda x: tf.data.TFRecordDataset(x),cycle_length=NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_CALL,num_parallel_calls=NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_CALL)
dataset=dataset.map(decode_memo_train).map(augmentation_Aggresive).repeat().batch(BATCH_SIZE)
batched_dataset=dataset.prefetch(PARSHING)
return batched_dataset
```

I have Removed the Interleave which has solved my problem. you can also avoid prefetching.